# Is it possible to deploy Kubernetes application through Bazel?

Tags: kubernetes, bazel

I want to automate the deployment procedure of my kubernetes pod manifest file through Bazel. I have gone through `k8s_object` in Bazel which takes information of the  k8s context, cluster and kubeconfig file , not sure how i can make use of it to deploy my application in k8s tenant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [k8s_object](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s#k8s_object) to interact with Kubernetes cluster.

You can [create a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) that will deploy your application to the cluster:

Here is an example `nginx-deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

You have to use that `yaml` file as a template in the bazel k8s_object, so it would look like this:
`k8s_object(name = "nginx", kind = "create", template = "nginx-deployment.yaml")`

Comment: Thanks  Crou!! I have an environment  same as mentioned in the  https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s#aliasing-eg-k8s_deploy ( Which I believe is same as creating K8s_object) .  I changed the cluster to my local K8s cluster, deployment file I kept in the BUILD.bazel file directory  and ran  this "bazel run :dev". Nothing got deploy in my K8s tenant instead this  has just  resolved my template and printed to  STDOUT.

Comment: Are you sure you correctly configured the cluster? Can you call any other commands?

Comment: yes cluster  is correctly configured. But i can  see the same behavior on  https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s#resolve, when  i run   "bazel run :dev". AFAIK run and build  are the only commands which can work  for this case. Do you have any working example on this ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need to use `bazel run :dev.create` or `bazel run :dev.apply`.

Comment: Thanks @Crou, this worked. But I encountered with  another issue after 'bazel run :dev.create'.

Comment: [root@localhost t2]# bazel  run //main:dev.create

Target //main:dev.create up-to-date:

  bazel-bin/main/dev.create <br/>

INFO: Elapsed time: 33.497s, Critical Path: 2.04s<br/>

INFO: 0 processes.<br/>

INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action<br/>

INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action<br/>

$ /usr/local/bin/kubectl --cluster=kubernetes --context= --user= create -f -

error: error parsing STDIN: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context<br/>

Comment: the deployment file is correct. I don't know where to  exactly look for this error.  Cloud you help me in that ?